# Difference between opening an appointment manually and from AddIn

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, office-2010

I am trying to open new appointment from the AddIn in Outlook 2010. When sending such an appointment the **page is hanging** and at times the appointment page is **not getting closed** after sending the appointment. But when I open the appointment from the file menu the explained problem is never seen and it is very fast. There might be a mistake I am making.

How I am opening the appointmentItem from the Ribbon.cs

```
var newAppointment =
   (AppointmentItem)(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem));
newAppointment.MeetingStatus = OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
newAppointment.Display(true);
```

How the ribbon button looks. On clicking which the above code gets executed.
[image: Sample Ribbon Button]

New Appointment Item is opened and not pressed sent yet.
[image: New Appointment item opened]

After pressing send, the appointment is sent to the users and saved to my calender but something is wrong and not getting closed.
[image: Distorted look]

When I tried to debug I found that it is reloading the ribbon, I am not sure if it reopening the page. But I am clue less.

What might be the reason? 
Let me know if I have presented clear enough.